# Restore From File History after Windows 10 Format/Reinstall

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup, file-history

I have been using Windows 10's File History to backup my files to a NAS I have at my house. Yesterday I formatted and reinstalled Windows to get a fresh start on the machine. I was hoping to just be able to go in, reconnect the File History directory and restore my files but that was not the case.

I reconnected the location where the backup was but it was not recognized (usually there is a checkbox that asks if you'd like to use an existing File History directory).

Is there a way I can reuse the existing directory on my NAS for my File History after reinstall?

Answer (score 5):

After your reinstall,

Control Panel -> System and Security -> File History -> Select Drive

Then select the drive or add the network location.
From there, you should click the checkbox "I want to use a previous backup on this File History drive".
Then in the box under "Select an existing backup:" you should see your previous backup. Select it and click Ok.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As of today (one year later), going through the Control Panel is still the only solution. Setting up the File History from the new Settings interface will create a new backup folder without any possibility to reuse an old backup.

Comment: Sounds like it worked for you. Lucky you! Even when I get the option to reuse a previous backup and use it I don't see the Snapshot in File History.